# Как правильно задать формат вывода строки

Tags: c#, строки

Есть следующий код:

```
  long hex;
  const string Text = "D0 9F D0 BE D1 81 D1 82 D0 BE D0 B9 "+
  "2C 20 D0 BF D0 B0 D1 80 D0 BE D0 B2 D0 BE D0 B7 2C 20 D0 "+
  "BD D0 B5 20 D1 81 D1 82 D1 83 D1 87 D0 B8 D1 82 D0 B5 20 "+
  "D0 BA D0 BE D0 BB D0 B5 D1 81 D0 B0 2E";

  string[] words = Text.Split(' ');

  foreach (string word in words)
  {
      hex = Convert.ToInt32(word, 16);
      Console.WriteLine("{0:x} : шестнадцатеричная : " + String.Format("{0:00000000}",Convert.ToString(hex, 2)), hex);

  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

По логике в консоль хочется вывести значение конвертированных значений, но вопреки заданному значению String.Format при выводе в консоль отсекаются нули слева.
Как правильно задать формат, чтобы в консоль выводилось по 8 бит?

Comment: У вас обрабочик в цикле ест и так по 8 бит. Что у вас показывает, и что вы хотите получить?

Comment: некоторые значения, например 20 конвертируется в 00100000, а выводится в консоли 100000, как получить формат {00000000}

Comment: Я только что понял, дело в том, что строка форматирования `:000000` на тип string не распространяется. Как вариант, можно его перепарсить в long, тогда для long форматёр добавит нули, а для string - точно нет. Вам уже даже ответили практически то же самое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант через [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
...
Console.WriteLine($"{hex:x} : шестнадцатеричная : {Convert.ToString(hex,2).PadLeft(8, '0')}");
...
```

Добавит недостающие нули слева.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ от @Vladislav Khapin правильный, я лишь поясню, почему `{0:00000000}"` не сработало. Дело в том, что [форматный символ `0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Specifier0) действует только на *числовые* аргументы. Но у вас этим аргументом является строка, а не число.

По поводу вывода *чисел* с выравниванием нулями, лучше MSDN никто не напишет: [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx).